# Why does the std::vector constructor accept initializer list by copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

When I was trying to understand the different types of initialization in modern C++, I came across the initialization of `std::vector<T>` with an initialization list. To allow initialization with initializer list data structure such as `std::vector<T>` should have a constructor that accepts initializer as the parameter. I observed is that `std::vector<T>` accepts the initializer list by copy not as a reference, accepting by copy when we have a huge number of elements can be very expensive. Why is it so is there any particular reason why the initializer list for taking it as a copy instead of reference?

From [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector](http://From%20https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector%20%20vector(%20std::initializer_list%3CT%3E%20init,%20%E2%80%A6%20);%09(9)%20%09(since%20C++11))

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, … ); (9)     (since C++11)
```

Why not?

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T>& init, … );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list),

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T`.
>
> Initializer lists may be implemented as a pair of pointers or pointer and length. Copying a `std::initializer_list` does not copy the underlying objects.

So, despite the fact that the `std::initializer_list` creates a temporary array, the elements of this array are not copied even if the `std::initializer_list` is passed by value. But if you like, you can accept objects of this type by a constant reference. This works great in my projects. For example:

```
auto some_function(const std::initializer_list<T>& list);
```

Answer (score 5):

`std::initializer_list` doesn't copy underlying objects.

As you can [read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> Copying a `std::initializer_list` does not copy the underlying objects.

So it doesn't really waste a lot of memory or time.